# Use OleLoadPicture to load a bitmap resource failes with 0x800a01e1 (CTL_E_INVALIDPICTURE)

Tags: winapi, gdi

I have a class in a project that loads a .bmp from a file and uses OleLoadPicture which works fine, there is already an interface to load from a resource but when I try to use it, I get the error `CTL_E_INVALIDPICTURE`.  The two different routines are below, why doesn't the resource version work?  The resource can be used on a dialog static control just fine, but in this case I want to load and draw it because it needs to be resized.

Here's those routines, it finds the resource via the RT_BITMAP and the id is IDB_MYBITMAP.  Any idea what is wrong?

***Edit***: It appears the `OleLoadPicture` doesn't support the .bmp format used,  when I put in a mark to ensure it was using a copy it ended up being a much larger file size and then it works.   So apparently it can't load RLE encoded .bmp?  I presume RLE because as mentioned, the .bmp works fine in Resource Editor and have it on a static control and the size is small.  Saving it the other way increased it from 36K up to 200K.

```
//////////////////
// Load from resource. Looks for "IMAGE" and "BITMAP" type.
//
BOOL CPicture::Load(HINSTANCE hinst, UINT nidres)
{
    // find resource in resource file
    HRSRC hrsrc = ::FindResource(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nidres), _T("IMAGE")); 
    if (!hrsrc) {
        hrsrc=::FindResource(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nidres), RT_BITMAP);
        if (!hrsrc)
            return FALSE;
    }

    // load resource into memory
    DWORD len = ::SizeofResource(hinst, hrsrc);
  if ( !len ) 
    return FALSE;

    HGLOBAL hresdata = ::LoadResource(hinst, hrsrc);
    if ( !hresdata )
        return FALSE;

    HGLOBAL hglobal = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_NODISCARD, len);
    if ( !hglobal )
    {
        ::FreeResource(hresdata);
        return FALSE;
    }

    char* pdest = reinterpret_cast<char*> ( ::GlobalLock(hglobal) );
    char* psrc = reinterpret_cast<char*> ( ::LockResource(hresdata) );
    if (!psrc || !pdest)
    {
        ::GlobalFree(hglobal);
        ::FreeResource(hresdata);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::CopyMemory(pdest,psrc,len);
    ::FreeResource(hresdata);
    ::GlobalUnlock(hglobal);

    // don't delete memory on object's release
    IStream* pstream = NULL;
    if ( ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hglobal,FALSE,&pstream) != S_OK )
    {
        ::GlobalFree(hglobal);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // create memory file and load it
    BOOL bret = Load(pstream);
  pstream->Release();

    ::GlobalFree(hglobal);

    return bret;
}

//////////////////
// Load from path name.
//
BOOL CPicture::Load(LPCTSTR pszpathname)
{
    HANDLE hfile = ::CreateFile(pszpathname, 
                                FILE_READ_DATA,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                NULL, 
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    if ( hfile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return FALSE;

  DWORD high=0;
    DWORD len = ::GetFileSize( hfile, &high);
    if (len == 0 || high || len > MAX_GRAPHIC_FILESIZE)
        return FALSE;

    HGLOBAL hglobal = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_NODISCARD, len);
    if ( !hglobal ) {
        ::CloseHandle(hfile);
        return FALSE;
    }

    char* lpbuffer = reinterpret_cast<char*> ( ::GlobalLock(hglobal) );

    DWORD dwbytesread;
    BOOL bret=ReadFile(hfile, lpbuffer, len, &dwbytesread, NULL) && dwbytesread==len;

    ::CloseHandle(hfile);
    ::GlobalUnlock(hglobal);


  if (bret) {
      // don't delete memory on object's release
      IStream* pstream = NULL;
      if ( ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hglobal,FALSE,&pstream) != S_OK )
      {
          ::GlobalFree(hglobal);
          return FALSE;
      }

      // create memory file and load it
      bret = Load(pstream);
    pstream->Release();
  }

    ::GlobalFree(hglobal);

    return bret;
}

//////////////////
// Load from stream (IStream). This is the one that really does it: call
// OleLoadPicture to do the work.
//
BOOL CPicture::Load(IStream* pstm)
{
    Free();

    HRESULT hr = OleLoadPicture(pstm, 0, FALSE, IID_IPicture, (void**)&m_spIPicture);

    return hr == S_OK;
}
```

Comment: What program was used to generate the bitmap file? Very few programs produce valid BMP files. Can you provide a minimal bitmap file, either as a hex dump or a base64-encoded version in the question?

Comment: Heck, I don't remember, but since OleLoadPicture couldn't handle the RLE bmp, I just changed the code to not even use those routines and just loaded the bitmap myself.  But the question may help someone hitting the same error for the same reason.